# Llenar una lista desde un formulario con ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: html, html5, asp.net-core

Desarrollo un proyecto sobre **ASP.NET Core 1.1** y tengo el siguiente inconveniente: Tengo un formulario con el cual creo un nuevo estudiante, este estudiante tiene una propiedad que es una lista de metas. Lo que deseo es agregar varias metas en el mismo formulario en el que se crea el estudiante.
Comparto algo de código para ilustrar el problema:

**Esta seria la vista modelo:**

```
public class StudenViewModel{
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
    public List<Goal> Goals {get; set;}
}

public Class Goal {
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Priority {get; set;}
}
```

**Este seria un fragmento de la vista**

```
@model StudentViewModel
<form class="form-horizontal ...>
    <div class="form-group>
        <label asp-for="FirstName"></label>
        <input asp-for="FirstName" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group>
        <label asp-for="LastName"></label>
        <input asp-for="LastName" />
    </div>
    @* Aqui iria el codigo necesario para agregar elementos (metas) a la lista*@
</form>
```

Se que esto se puede lograr fácilmente usando *frameworks frontend*, incluso lo he hecho anteriormente usando **React**, pero para este proyecto en especifico quisiera lograrlo usando solamente **HTML**, **JS**, **C#**.

Agradezco su ayuda, de antemano.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hace tiempo que encontre la solucion asi que la publico por si le es de ayuda a alguien:

Deben implementarse los input sin usar asp-for, en vez de eso usar la propiedad name haciendo referencia al indice de cada elemento, asi:

```
@model StudentViewModel
<form class="form-horizontal">
   ...
<div class="form-group">
    <input name="Goals[0].Name" />
    <input name="Goals[0].Priority" />
    <input name="Goals[1].Name" />
    <input name="Goals[1].Priority" />
</div>
</form>
```

Si se requiere dinamico se puede implementar una funcion mediante Javascript para agregar o remover inputs y un contador global que tenga la cuenta de cuantos elementos van a ser insertados en la lista. La numeracion de los indices debe ser consecutiva porque de lo contraro el sistema no sera capaz de bindear los datos hacia el modelo.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba lo siguiente, tener varios inputs asignados a la propiedad del modelo:

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Register" method="post">
    <input id="txtGoal1" type="text" asp-for="Goals" />
    <input id="txtGoal2" type="text" asp-for="Goals" />
    <input id="txtGoal3" type="text" asp-for="Goals" />
    <input type="submit" value="Registrar" />
</form>
```

Y en el controller debe quedar algo así:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Register(StudentViewModel model)
    {
        // TODO: Guardar los datos

        return View("Index");
    }
```

Después se podrían agregar dinámicamente los inputs al formulario

Comment: lo he intentado pero solo funciona si el tipo de la lista es primitivo. Voy a actualizar la pregunta porque lo que enrealidad necesito es hacerlo con una clase. Sabes como podria lograrlo para por ejemplo apuntar a las propiedades de una clase?

Answer (score 0):

¿Por qué no pones un textarea y que se separen las metas con punto y coma (;) y las prioridades de la meta con comas (,)? 
Una cadena de ejemplo sería:

```
Programación,Alta;Bases de datos,Media
```

Así obtendrías un string que puedes manipular del lado del servidor con un [String.Split()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) (más fácil de programar, pero pones una carga adicional en tu servidor) para insertarlo dentro de la lista correspondiente.

Esta sería una solución que simplificaría el desarrollo en el front-end pero añadiría carga al usuario.

Otra opción podría ser tratar el textarea con JQuery de forma que lo que envías al servidor sea un arreglo de JSON y lo "deserialices" en el servidor a una lista de C#. Así reducirías algo de carga en tu back-end, pero no conozco cuál sea la clase que te permita trabajar con JSON en ASP.NET Core.